# Confused with the word "before" is it okay to use it like this?

Tags: word-usage

I know that the word "before" can be used to mean "In front of" and when something happens before a particular time. For eg. :

*I'm standing **before** you.*

*I'll come **before** you leave.*

Now my question is can I use the sentence:

*I Came **before** you*

*I was there **before** You*

To mean that i came earlier than you?
Or does it mean that I came in front of you?
And I was there in front of you?

Thanks in Advance,
Rishabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ! the sentences are correct.

```
I Came before you.

I was there before You
```

As you said in question you want to convey that *you came earlier than him/her* for that case I would advice you to use "ahead"

```
I came ahead of you.
```

Comment: And can i say "I was there ahead of you"? Or will it mean i was there in front of you?

Comment: Don't Forget to accept the question if it was helpful.

Comment: Yeah sure, Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes,I was there ahead of you ! is correct . I am happy i was helpful